# Expection from joint density distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Given $f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$, $0<x<y$ and $0<y$, find $E(X)$. 
I tried to find $E(X)$ by finding the marginal pdf of $x$, but I realized that I was unable to do so because $\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$ is not integrable with respect to $y$. Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: The hint should be from the fact: for $x<y$, the joint density has no $x$ term.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth what do you mean? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: You have $f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-y}}{y}$ for $0<x<y$. And the joint density only has terms involving $y$. What does this say about the joint density?

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(y)$? But it requires me to find the expected value of $x$. So you mean $E(X)=0?$ @TonyHellmuth

Comment: I think I am confusing both of us! We know from Bayes rule that $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$. Can you take it from there? We know the law of total expectation says $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$

Comment: i know i have to find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, but I am unable to find $f_Y(y)$ as the function is not integrable with respect to $y$.. @TonyHellmuth

Comment: You cannot find $f_X(x)$ using standard integrals. BUT $f_Y(y)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$ is sure achievable :) Always remember we want to integrate with respect to the variable we want to rid of!

Comment: oh okay, i forgot the law of total expectation. this will be the key point to solve the problem . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the joint density is constant with respect to $x$ over its support $\{(x,y): 0\leqslant y<\infty, 0<x<y\}$. It follows that conditioned on $Y=y$, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,y)$, and so $\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y] = \frac12 y$. Now, the density of $Y$ is given by
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_0^y \frac{e^{-y}}y\ \mathsf dx = e^{-y},$$ and so by the law of total expectation,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac12 y e^{-y}\ \mathsf dy\\ 
&= \frac12 \int_0^\infty y e^{-y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac12.
\end{align}